# Can Vim's substitute command handle recursive pattern as sed's "t labe"?

Tags: regex, vim

Just a random example:

```
aaa 01 02 03 04 05
```

The number of numbers behind "aaa" is unfixed. The expected result of replacement is:

```
aaa 01
aaa 02
aaa 03
aaa 04
aaa 05
```

I know how to make it with sed's "t label" or with Vim using commands like

```
:%s/\v%(^(\a+) .{-})@<= (\d+)/\r\1 \2/g
```

but I wonder is there a recursive way to handle this with Vim.

Answer (score 3):

### Using vim substitution (`:s`)

**1 Using `:s` and confirmation to do the job:**

```
:%s/\s\+/\raaa /gc
```

When vim asks you for confirmation, you press `n` then `a`.

**2 Call functions in vim's `:s` command:**

```
%s/\v((\S+)\s+\S+)(.*)/\=submatch(1).substitute(submatch(3), '\s\+',"\r".submatch(2)."&",'g')
```

The above command looks long, but it is pretty straightforward.

### Using vim macro

If I were you, I would do it with macro in vim. Personally, I feel it would be the "vim" way:

Assume the line in your example sits in line1, and your cursor is on the first column. You press:

```
qqyw2f<Space>i<Enter><Ctrl-r>"<Esc>0q
```

To record a macro and save it in `q` register. Next, you can just replay the macro x times, for example:

```
99@q
```

and see how vim does the job. The total number of keystrokes to finish the job would be less than 20.

It looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
:%s/\v(\S+)(^(\S+)\s+\S+\s.{-})@<=/\r\3 \1/g
```

**Details**

- `\v` - very magic mode ON
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: any one or more non-whitespace chars
- `(^(\S+)\s+\S+\s.{-})@<=` - that are preceded with (`()@<=` is a positive lookbehind construct, it is, however, counted as a group):

  - `^` - start of string
  - `(\S+)` - Group 3: any one or more non-whitespace chars
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
  - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
  - `\s` - 1 whitespace char
  - `.{-}` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible

Result:

```
aaa 01
aaa 02
aaa 03
aaa 04
aaa 05
```